# How to read and map the description of the google search result using python request ?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-search

I used python requests to find the google search result. I'm able to find the links and descriptions but how can I map the links with its respective description.

Below is the code and its output:

```
req=urllib2.Request('http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q='+'cat')  
sock=urllib2.urlopen(req)
data = sock.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
if(soup):
    links = soup.findAll('cite')
    spans = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "st"})
    for link, span in ((l,s) for l in links for s in spans):
        print link.text, span.get_text()
```

**Output:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat, The domestic cat (Latin: Felis catus) is a small, typically furry, carnivorous mammal. They are often called house cats when kept as indoor pets or simply cats

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat, A non-profit organisation, run entirely by volunteers who want to improve the welfare of stray cats in Singapore.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat, Manufacturer of construction and mining equipment, diesel and natural gas engines, industrial gas turbines, and a wide offering of related services.

www.catwelfare.org/,The domestic cat (Latin: Felis catus) is a small, typically furry, carnivorous mammal. They are often called house cats when kept as indoor pets or simply cats

www.catwelfare.org/, A non-profit organisation, run entirely by volunteers who want to improve the welfare of stray cats in Singapore.

www.catwelfare.org/, Manufacturer of construction and mining equipment, diesel and natural gas engines, industrial gas turbines, and a wide offering of related services.

etc..

The same link is mapped with all the description of the google search result.

**The required output is,**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat, The domestic cat (Latin: Felis catus) is a small, typically furry, carnivorous mammal. They are often called house cats when kept as indoor pets or simply cats

www.catwelfare.org/, A non-profit organisation, run entirely by volunteers who want to improve the welfare of stray cats in Singapore.

www.cat.com/,Manufacturer of construction and mining equipment, diesel and natural gas engines, industrial gas turbines, and a wide offering of related services.

Kindly help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically accidentally doing `funcutils.permutations` in the line `for link, span in ((l,s) for l in links for s in spans):` which logically reads "for all combinations of links in `links` and spans in `spans`, do the following:".

What you want is to iterate over *either* the links *or* the spans and, for whichever you choose, get the associated link/span. You'll probably need to do a `find()` on a common outer HTML element and iterate over that, in each iteration grabbing the `link` and `span`.

Comment: Thanks @jknupp. Yeah I get an basic idea and the outline of your explanation. But i'm not sure how to implement. Could you please help me.

Comment: Without knowing the structure of the HTML page, I can't give you the exact code. Given how far you've gotten, though, the description in the answer should probably be enough.

Comment: Okay. I shall try Jknupp